# Redirect rules with "+" in the string not working

Tags: redirect, nginx

I'm using `Nginx` and have setup some redirect rules in the `.conf` for the site, eg

```
if ($query_string ~ "Search=shelving"){ rewrite .*$ /shelving.html? redirect; }
```

So any url with `"Search=shelving"` will redirect to `/shelving.html`

This works fine, but I have other rules that have + in the string, which are not working eg

```
if ($query_string ~ "Search=metal+shelving"){ rewrite .*$ /shelving.html? redirect; }
```

this is not working, and I think that the + is breaking it, is there anyway around this?

Thanks

Edit:

An example of an url I'm look to redirect is:

https://example.com/SearchResults.aspx?Search=metal+shelving

to 
https://example.com/shelving.html

Comment: I guess it's url-encoded to `%2B`. Anyway if it's query parameter, it's better to use `$arg_Search` variable.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Alexey, can you give me a bit more info about the `$arg_Search` variable?  thanks

Comment: http://nginx.org/r/$arg_ Nginx automatically creates variables for query parameters. E.g. for request `/?a=1&hello=2` there are variables `$arg_a` and `$arg_hello`.

Comment: I tried using $arg like in this example http://serverfault.com/questions/160790/nginx-rewrite-for-an-url-with-parameters  but still not working, I think the + is still an issue

Comment: What request url you have and what you need to do with it?

Comment: I have updated the original question with a example url, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just update your nginx rule like this

```
if ($query_string ~ "Search=metal\+shelving"){ rewrite .*$ /shelving.html? redirect; }
```

Comment: Thanks harshad, this works too but alot more simple (alot less edits for me to do in the redirect file)

Answer (score 0):

I would write something like this:

```
map $arg_search $redirect_url {
  default "";
  "metal shelving" /shelving.html;
  "metal+shelving" /shelving.html;
  "metal%2bshelving" /shelving.html;
  "metal%2Bshelving" /shelving.html;
}

server {
  ...
  if ($redirect_url) {
    return 301 $redirect_url;
  }
  ...
}
```

Just to cover all possible url encodings.

Comment: `"metal+shelving" /shelving.html;` alone  was enough to make it work.  only problem is that I have 100s of redirects like that to do within 1000s of others that I have separated off into a different file that is included into the main .conf (just to keep things clean).  But I have enough now it make it work. Thanks for your help